# Delphi 5 is required by app for custom plugins -- are newer Delphi versions backward compatible?

Tags: delphi

The plugin API documentation for an app I use requires Delphi 5 for plugin development, but I'm having a difficult time locating a copy of Delphi 5 or docs for it. Are any later versions of Delphi able to create BPL files identical to those produced by Delphi 5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are any later versions of Delphi able to create BPL files identical to those produced by Delphi 5?

No, binary compatibility between versions is a weak point of Delphi. You really need D5, or a newer version of that app.

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference between Standard and Professional? I can't find a feature matrix for version 5.

Comment: IIRC the database components are not included in D5 Standard

Comment: IIRC main difference between standard and professional is that standard didn't have the data aware controls / didn't support database development out of the box.

Comment: I am sure you don't want standard. Apart from not having database capability it also lacked quite a few other controls. My memory is weak on that account, though. Just in case you want to access ADO databases: If I remember correctly, ADO was part of Delphi 5 enterprise edition (but also available as a separate product).

Comment: Just for reference, this pages explicitly states D5 is no longer available. But you could try getting a used version. http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/previous-versions

Comment: +1 I didn't know that. Just to get this straight, OP would have been able to write plugins in *any* Delphi version if the application used plain dll's but not when using bpl's? *(for the sake of argument, I'm ignoring any other benefits that bpl's have over dll's)*

Comment: @lieven: basically, yes. BPLS are very brittle in the version dept.

Comment: Using bpl's ties you to Delphi but being tied to a *specific* version of Delphi would be a real showstopper if I were to make my application plug-able.

Comment: I would use COM for plugins. Using .bpl files is crazy.